# how to get the html source of the selected text in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Suppose I have written 5 lines in ckeditor and I have selected the 2nd and 3rd line. How to get the html source of the selected text.Assuming the code will be selected in continuation always.

Comment: copy it into another ckeditor and press the view source button, otherwise there is no way apart from pressing the view source button and then searching for the text you have selected

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSelectionHtml()
{
editor=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var sel = editor.getSelection();
var ranges = sel.getRanges();
var el = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div");
for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
    el.append(ranges[i].cloneContents());
}
  console.log("OrgHtml:\n"+el.getHtml());
  return el.getHtml();
}
```

Use this function to get the selected text's InnerHtml value.I'm using this function also.

Answer (score 0):

**All selected HTML nodes - CKEditor**

**Note:** It all depends on the current structure of data in your ckeditor. If you have selected a text which is inside a tag and text is partially selected then complete tag will get returned.

**Note eg:**

```
<p>my ckeditor text</p> enclosed in a p-tag
```

if you have selected **"editor te"** then complete **p-tag** will get return as you said you need HTML not selected text.

**Code:**

```
var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0] //editor is instance of your ck-editor
var selectedHTML = [];
console.log(range.startPath().elements[0].$, 'first')
selectedHTML.push(range.startPath().elements[0].$)
var selectedSibling = "";
if(range.startPath().elements[0].$ != range.endPath().elements[0].$) {
    selectedSibling = range.startContainer.$.parentNode.nextElementSibling
    while(selectedSibling && (selectedSibling != range.endPath().elements[0].$)) {
        console.log(selectedSibling, 'next')
        selectedHTML.push(selectedSibling)
        selectedSibling = selectedSibling.nextElementSibling
    }
    console.log(range.endPath().elements[0].$, 'last')
    selectedHTML.push(range.endPath().elements[0].$)
}
console.log(selectedHTML, 'selected HTML  Tags')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your active selection with

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }
    text = container.innerHTML;
}
```

the HTML you selected will be stored in the variable `text`.